# why does this function always give me an error

Tags: python, function

i wanna try and make quick sort on my own but the functions always give me an error when trying to execute them

the code for now:

```
import random
pivot = 0
mop = 0
vop = 0
bobl = 0
lista = [2, 5, 1, 7, 9, 4, 6, 3, 8]
def mopcom():
    if lista.index(mop)>lista.index(pivot):
        mop = random.choice(lista)
        mopcom()
def vopcom():
    if lista.index(vop)<lista.index(pivot):
        vop = random.choice(lista)
        vopcom()
pivot = random.choice(lista)
mop = random.choice(lista)
vop = random.choice(lista)
mopcom()
```

the 2 functions that are causing issues:

```
def mopcom():
    if lista.index(mop)>lista.index(pivot):
        mop = random.choice(lista)
        mopcom()
def vopcom():
    if lista.index(vop)<lista.index(pivot):
        vop = random.choice(lista)
        vopcom()
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/antem/OneDrive/Radna površina/pametno.py", line 22, in <module>
    mopcom()
  File "C:/Users/antem/OneDrive/Radna površina/pametno.py", line 11, in mopcom
    if lista.index(mop)>lista.index(pivot):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mop' referenced before assignment
```

please dont tell me that im doing quick sort wrong, as I want to try to do this on my own. just tell me why this is giving me errors

Comment: You assign to variable `mop` in function `mopcom`.  That makes `mop` a local variable unless you declare it global.  Just add `global mop` at the top of the function body to make it reference the global.  Of course, using globals for this is terrible coding style, but that's a different issue.

Comment: There are hundreds of previous questions about this error message. Did you do any research before posting?

Comment: Since you assign to `mop` in the function, Python assumes it is a local variable, but since you try to read it before it is assigned to, you get this error. If you wanted to use the global `mop`, start the function with `global mop` (it's not generally a good way to code these things though and you can probably think of better ways that don't require globals)

Answer (score 0):

## summary: Use function parameters.

Those global variables aren't doing you any favors.

You wrote:

```
def mopcom():
    if lista.index(mop)>lista.index(pivot):
        mop = random.choice(lista)
    ...
```

Line 2 *reads* `mop`, and line 3 *writes* to it.
Well, it writes to a *different* `mop`,
it writes to a newly created local variable of that name.
Then you exit the function, the local goes out of scope,
and it is garbage collected.

You *could* use the `global` keyword.
But it would be much much better to pass the relevant
variables as formal parameters,
or to make this a `class` and refer to `self.mop`.

Answer (score -1):

In python, variables are scoped by default. Consider this snippet:

```
x = 3

def foo():
    x = 4 # This is a new, different variable also called x

foo()
print(x) # Prints 3
```

Because of this, `mop` inside of `mopcom` is treated as a different value. To fix this, add the line `global mop`. This tells python that `mop` is actually a global value.

```
import random
pivot = 0
mop = 0
vop = 0
bobl = 0
lista = [2, 5, 1, 7, 9, 4, 6, 3, 8]
def mopcom():
    global mop
    global pivot
    global lista
    if lista.index(mop)>lista.index(pivot):
        mop = random.choice(lista)
        mopcom()
def vopcom():
    global vop
    global lista
    global pivot
    if lista.index(vop)<lista.index(pivot):
        vop = random.choice(lista)
        vopcom()
pivot = random.choice(lista)
mop = random.choice(lista)
vop = random.choice(lista)
mopcom()
```

Comment: Please do not recommend using global state.